# Trivial No in Prolog returns Yes

Tags: prolog

I have a  simple predicate in prolog that when MaxScore >0, it gives yes, otherwise is no. So if MaxScore is 0, then obviously the result is No. But this doesn't happen. Look closer at this: [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18710637/prologIsInsane.png]

Or corresponding code:

```
aiPlay(PlayerNum, Board, Pos, BotType) :-
    aiTryAll(Board, PlayerNum, ScoreList, 0),
    scoreListGetPos(ScoreList, 1, Pos, MaxScore),
    write('MaxScore: '), write(MaxScore), nl,
    MaxScore > 0.
```

And corresponding output:

```
| ? myQuery(Pos).
MaxScore: 0
MaxScore: 0
MaxScore: 1
Pos = 6 ?
yes
| ?
```

I am getting insane with this. Anyone have a clue about what is happening?

Comment: Please try to work some more on your acceptante rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a problem; consider this code:

```
foo(0).
foo(0).
foo(1).

bar:-
    foo(X),
    write(X), nl,
    X > 0.
```

Prolog will first unify `X` with `0` (from the first `foo(0)`), will print the output and then fail since `0 > 0` is false. Then prolog will backtrack and pick the second `foo(0)`; again the same. Finally, `X` will be unified with `1` and `bar` will return `true`.

Naturall, side-effects like printing cannot be reversed/backtracked, so in the terminal you will see:

```
0
0
1
true
```

How you solve it depends on what you want to do; if you want to print just `Max Core = 1` then you can do the printing after you check if `MaxScore>0`. Generally though, it's better to do the printing (if it's required) at the very end, and not in a predicate deep in the program.

Oh, by the way, it's better to post the actual code and the output instead of a screenshot; it makes it easier to copy-paste-debug your code. Also, it is advised to give a runnable example: half of the predicates you use in `aiPlay/4` are undefined so I'm just guessing that the problem is what I mentioned above :p

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I lost 3 hours figuring that was from backtrack, but if this happen is because one of my predicated are mall formed, since they are strict rules to don't allow maxscore to be >0. Regarding the printscreen, I thaught would be more clear to understand :D thanks for all.